# Node JS not displaying UTF-8 character from Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I was doing some web crawling and noticed that I was getting some weird documents with characters like so "�".

I visited the problematic website, but there was no visible problem with the document enconding itself.

I took the buffer that was being displayed incorrectly and started testing, and the problem seems to be in node js?

```
    var actual = new Buffer([0x50, 0x72, 0x65, 0xe7, 0x6f]) // this is the buffer I got
    var correct = 'Preço' // This is what I expected to be displayed

    console.log('Correct: ', correct)
    console.log('Actual:', actual.toString('utf8'))

    // Test code per code
    console.log(correct.charCodeAt(0) + '=' + parseInt(actual[0]))
    console.log(correct.charCodeAt(1) + '=' + parseInt(actual[1]))
    console.log(correct.charCodeAt(2) + '=' + parseInt(actual[2]))
    console.log(correct.charCodeAt(3) + '=' + parseInt(actual[3]))
    console.log(correct.charCodeAt(4) + '=' + parseInt(actual[4]))
```

Outputs:

```
Correct:  Preço
Actual: Pre�o
80=80
114=114
101=101
231=231
111=111
```

As you see, all bytes corresponds to the same char code! How could they be yielding different results?

Comment: Are you sure it's `utf-8`?

Comment: @MinusFour The buffer is definitely a valid utf8 char code sequence, I looked at a utf8 table to check

Comment: Right, so you were trying to get `U+00E7` out of `0xe7`, but it isn't. `U+00E7` is `0xC3, 0xA7` in utf-8.

Comment: @MinusFour It worked...

Comment: I'd try and see if it works with `binary` encoding, instead of `utf8` (with your original buffer)

Comment: @MinusFour Yeah, it looks like part of the buffer it's actually in windows-1250, while other parts UTF-8....

Answer (score 0):

Try `iconv`:

```
var actual = new Buffer([0x50, 0x72, 0x65, 0xe7, 0x6f]) // this is the buffer I got

var correct = 'Preço' // This is what I expected to be displayed

console.log('Correct: ', correct)
console.log('Actual:', actual.toString('utf8'))

var iconv = require('iconv');
var converter = new iconv.Iconv('windows-1250', 'utf8');
var data = converter.convert(actual).toString();
console.log('iconv: ',data);
```

Comment: Any tips in what to do with multiple encoding in the same documents? As I'm  seeing, they have windows-1250 and utf-8 in the same document! That's part of the problem I'm having, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code sample for 2-byte presentation of chars in strings. Buffer is trimming higher byte in your above example.

```
function SpecialCharsTest (str)
  {
    //mix-data = '€uro' // This is what I expected to be displayed, € sign is 2-byte 0x20AC
    console.log('InStr: ', str);
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    var strLen=str.length;
    for (var i=0; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    console.log('InStr to bufView Array (2-byte):      ', bufView);
    console.log('InStr to buf back to String (2-byte): ' + String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf)));  
    return buf;
  }
```

Result:

```
InStr:  €uro
InStr to bufView Array (2-byte):       Uint16Array(4) [8364, 117, 114, 111]
InStr to buf back to String (2-byte): €uro
```